# Why func_get_args return me an array inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays

With this code:

```
$var = array(3,5,6);

function test() {
echo "<pre>";
print_r(func_get_args());
echo "</pre>";
}

test($var);
```

I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

)
```

Why are there two arrays ? I was expected that only the second array would be print

Comment: If you want to pass the values in `$var` as individual values, look at argument packing/unpacking with the splat (`...`) operator: `test(...$var);`

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you a tip that will, I hope, help you find answers easily from the documentation ;

```
 $var = array(3,5,6);

 function test() {
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r(func_get_args());
   echo "</pre>";
 } 
 test($var);
```

Why are there two arrays ?
You can easily find the answer from the documentation with more explanations and examples;
To this particular example :
First you look for `func_get_args()` in the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.func-get-args.php)
**func_get_args :** 
 **Explination 1** : Returns an array comprising a function's argument list
**Explination 2** :  Returns an array in which each element is a copy of the corresponding member of the current user-defined function's argument list.

From these explinations you got that `func_get_args` return an array but remember that in your code you did use it in combination with another function `print_r`.
Then the next is check the [documentation for that function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) as well;
**print_r :**
**Explination 1** : `print_r` — Prints human-readable information about a variable;
 `mixed print_r ( mixed $expression [, bool $return = false ] )`
**Explination 2 :** If given a string, integer or float, the value itself will be printed. If given an array, values will be presented in a format that shows keys and elements. Similar notation is used for objects.
When the return parameter is `TRUE`, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the return value is `TRUE`.

From the documentation i can easily find the answer i'm looking with examples along the way.
Hope that you will find useful

Answer (score 0):

You pass an array that is one argument and one value in the returned array that contains the array. So you have an array entry for the argument that is itself an arry

In PHP >= 5.6 you can use argument unpacking ([Variable length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)) with `...`:

```
test(...$var);
```

Or you could pass the array elements as individual arguments:

```
call_user_func_array('test', $var);
```

Both yield:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 6
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the normal behaviour of [this function](http://php.net/func_get_args) :

> #### Return Values
>
> Returns an **array** in which each element is a copy of the corresponding
>   member of the current user-defined function's argument list.

```
$var = array(3,5,6);

function test() {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(func_get_args());
    echo "</pre>";
}

test('string');
```

this will output an array as follows:

```
Array (
    [0] => string
)
```

and as long as you are sending an array as parameter, so the function will print out the passed array as an element of the parent array :

for example , passing a string and an array :

```
$var = array(3,5,6);
function test() {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(func_get_args());
    echo "</pre>";
}

test('string', $var);
```

this will output:

```
Array (
    [0] => string 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 3 
        [1] => 5 
        [2] => 6 
    ) 
)
```